# Can I remove the null=True parameter from a django ForeignKey?

Tags: python, django

I have two models, `foo` and `bar`. They already exists in my database with many instances each. Now, I realized that there is a relation that should be added. Therefor, I wish to add a ForeignKey between`foo` and `bar`.

```
class foo():
  # lots of stuff
  bar = models.ForeignKey(bar, related_name='foo', null=True)
```

I actually don't want the key to be nullable, but since they already exists, I need to add it because the existing rows need to be populated.

Can I later remove the `null=True` parameter once all instances have the foreignKey field are populated?

Comment: Yes you can remove the parameter once all the existing field have data

Comment: You can write a migration that populates the relationships with a `RunPython` migration… https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/writing-migrations/

Comment: Once you remove it, make migrations and migrate, you'll be asked to give a default value during the migration if any of the rows don't have a value. You can use the id of one of your `bar`s then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, basically to reach this you need to do three steps

1. Create a first migration, where you create your field as nullable
2. Create a second migration to populate already existing fields
3. Create a third migration where you set the field as not nullable

A very good step by step is explained [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/09/26/how-to-create-django-data-migrations.html)